# Classe não encontrada em compilação pelo CMD do Windows

Tags: java, cmd

não estou conseguindo executar meus algoritmos em JAVA pelo terminal do Windows 8.1 .

Acontece que sempre dá erro de classe não encontrada, já coloquei os arquivos .class junto com .java e mesmo assim não encontra.

O que faço pra resolver?

Segue uns prints para ilustrar minha dúvida.

**Todos os arquivos juntos na mesmo pasta →**

[image: Arquivos juntos...]

**Execução do comando javac sistema.java no CMD →**
[image: Comandos...]

PS: já usei o comando **javac sistema.java pessoa.java aluno.java** e NADA.

Comment: No arquivo `aluno.java`, a classe "aluno" esta definida como `Aluno` ou `aluno`?

Comment: Provavelmente o @ViníciusGobboA.deOliveira está certo, a classe deve ser Aluno.

Comment: Aki está o código da minha classe:

http://prntscr.com/8mmgg1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para commpilar as classes você deve salvar a classe com o mesmo nome que você
vai usar para chamar a classe pelo cmd.

```
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, World");
    }
}
```

Voce deve chamar pelo cmd dessa forma:
javac **HelloWorld**.java

É possível nomear uma classe com qualquer nome suportado pela linguagem.Mas é interessante seguir algumas regras adotadas:

Toda classe deve começar com uma letra maiúscula ,caso o nome de uma classe seja composto por mais de uma palavra, a primeira letra de cada palavra deve ser em maiúscula.Não declarar uma classe com qualquer caracter especial (@, #, $, %, &, *, _, etc...). 
A palavra selecionada deverá refletir o propósito da classe.

Sempre coloque a classe em algum pacote.